# How do I set up automatic project creation with node/grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, build-system

I have just started using node/grunt and loving it, though I was wondering if there was a way to when creating and setting a project, to import a template of folder and files. I use to just copy and paste from a template zip I have that contains, js, sass and css folders with corresponding files and a index.html.

So, I would like to know how I can automate this creation. Along with that, I assume there would be a way to quickly install all the modules I normally use?

If this isn't possible, would it be worth looking into gulp to try and do something similar?

I have been thinking of ways of doing this, and putting the template files onto github came to mind, so all it would need todo is download them and put them into a folder.

Comment: Yeoman generator is something you're looking for.

Comment: @Ankur Ok, so that I have this right. Yeoman sets up a structure of files and folders, and that's it? Then I have grunt to do the compiling and processing stuff?

Comment: exactly. Yeoman for scaffolding, then Grunt/Gulp/Webpack anything you want for compilation and build.